# window.getComputedStyles() doesn't work with Jest and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to run basic assertions about the styling of my component. Right now I am running them on the default React app that the CRA template gives you:

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.test.js

```js
test("computed styles", () => {
  render(<App />);
  const app = document.querySelector(".App");
  const appStyles = window.getComputedStyle(app);

  console.log(appStyles.width);
});
```

Nothing is logged to the console. I run the same code in the browser, and in the app itself, and it returns `1440px`, the width of my screen. But in Jest, it returns nothing.

Comment: Where does `render` function come from? Are you using RTL?

Comment: Yes @slideshowp2, React Testing Library is included in CRA boilerplate.